# How to add background color to each page in xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, background-color, xsl-fo

I have to add a background color to all the pages I will have in the resulting PDF. I have tried to so using the following code but it does not color the entire page, just some parts of it

```
        <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="frictionalFiction" >
            <fo:region-body margin="1in" background-color="#D2B48C"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="0.5in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
```

How do I get it to color all the pages in the PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer is to set the color of only the region-before and set it's extent equal to the page-height.

Comment: I did as you said and it worked, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you have to add color also to `fo:region-before` and `fo:region-after`

```
<fo:region-before background-color="#D2B48C" />
<fo:region-after background-color="#D2B48C" extent="0.5in" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code setting background color to all the pages:

```
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:block-container background-color="#D2B48C" position="absolute" height="297mm" width="100%">
            <fo:block>Other headers</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:static-content>
```